# C, Showing count of repeating symbols

Tags: c

Need to figure out a code that counts all the repeating symbols in a string. As you can see below, so far so good.

And here starts the tricky part, at the end of the code I want to output symbols in an order they were typed which had for example 2 occurences in a string, and I got problems figuring that out.

```
int counts[256] = { 0 };

int i;
size = strlen(text);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
counts[(int)(text[i])]++;
}

for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
printf("The %d. character has %d occurrences.\n", i, counts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do u want?

Comment: You'll have to sort it.

Comment: This is dangerous if `char` is `signed` and you have character values larger than 127.  @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey No, you don't need to sort it.  See the current answer.

Comment: @paddy Good point about signed/unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(counts[(int)(text[i])] == 2)
        printf("%d", (int)(text[i]));
```

The first line loops through your source string for the order of occurences.
The second line checks if it was captured in the counts array as occuring only twice.
If it was we print the char code on the third line.

To only print the character once:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(counts[(int)(text[i])] == 2) {
        printf("%d", (int)(text[i]));
        counts[(int)(text[i])] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>=` instead of `==`?

Comment: It depends on if you want to check whether the character happened only twice (`==`), or if it happened at least twice (`>=`). I'm going to edit my answer to specify that, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for help! But, the code shows repeating symbol twice, while I need it to appear only once. for example if I input string "ABCA" it should give out "A" instead of "AA" any ideas?

Comment: Inspired mentioned it first, so I don't want to take credit, but after printing it out, reset the `counts` for it to 0, I'll update the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the source string again and for each character look into your `counts` array.

If you don't want to print the same statistics for every occurence of repeating character, you can reset the corresponding `counts` value to zero just after you print the statistics, and have an additional check before printing.

Comment: You should probably copy the buffer before you modify it if you need it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of **Inspired**'s answer:

```
int counts[256] = { 0 };

char text[] = "Hello, world!";

int i, size = strlen(text);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    counts[(unsigned int)(text[i])]++;
}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (counts[(unsigned int)text[i]] > 1)
    {
        printf("%c", text[i]);
        counts[(unsigned int)text[i]] = 0; // Remove to print repeats.
    }
}
```

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey, howcome?

Comment: Should be `> 0` or `>= 1`.  Not `> 1`.  Will someone *please* cast `(unsigned char)text[i]` before indexing!!

Comment: @Inspired says you need to iterate through the source string again.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey, isn't that what the last `for` loop is doing? Also, paddy, I'm *assuming* that the OP wants to print characters which appear two or more times.

Comment: @JosuéMolina You're simply printing the counts of all characters in ASCII order, not in the order they appeared in the string.  According to your example, you should print the character counts of `'H'` first, because it appeared first in your string.

Comment: @JosuéMolina @paddy is trying to prevent using a negative index on the array (e.g. `counts[-1]`).

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey, I am not printing them in ASCII order... did you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Make a key,count pair, like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* text = "count this text";
    char *keys = new char[strlen(text)];
    int* count = new int[strlen(text)];
    int last = 0; int j=0;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(text); i++){
      for(j=0; j<last; j++){
        if(keys[j]==text[i]) break;
      }
      if(keys[j]==text[i]){
        count[j]++;
      } else {
        keys[last]=text[i];
        count[last]=1;
        last++;
      }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<last; i++){

        printf("%c %d\n", keys[i], count[i]);
    }
}
```

so you keep the order in the text and get the count.

On execution the output is:

```
c 1
o 1
u 1
n 1
t 4
2
h 1
i 1
s 1
e 1
x 1
```

Comment: Ugh.  This is not even C, your arrays are not initialised, and the algorithm is hideous.

Comment: Ok, this is not C but easily converted, arrays don't need to be initialized, that is a lost of time, and algorithms gives what the Op wanted without much fuss